# Making a function run code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a app with python and Tkinter. Say I added two buttons one for MAIN and one for NEWS when I press MAIN make the function mainthumsfun run and set the variables and after that run gui function with the new variables. How would I make that work?

```
import StringIO
import Scraper
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('RazeTheWorld')

maintumbs = Scraper.maintumbs()
newstumbs = Scraper.newstumbs()

def mainthumsfun():
    url0 = mainthumbs[0]
    url1 = mainthumbs[1]
    url2 = mainthumbs[2]
    url3 = mainthumbs[3]

def newsthumbsfun():
    url0 = newsthumbs[0]
    url1 = newsthumbs[1]
    url2 = newsthumbs[2]
    url3 = newsthumbs[3]

def gui():
    imgf1 = urllib.urlopen(url0)
    imgwr1 = StringIO.StringIO(imgf1.read())
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgwr1))
    panel1 = tk.Label(root, image=image1)
    panel1.grid(row=0,column=0)

    imgf2 = urllib.urlopen(url1)
    imgwr2 = StringIO.StringIO(imgf2.read())
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgwr2))
    panel2 = tk.Label(root, image=image2)
    panel2.grid(row=1,column=0)

    imgf3 = urllib.urlopen(url2)
    imgwr3 = StringIO.StringIO(imgf3.read())
    image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgwr3))
    panel3 = tk.Label(root, image=image3)
    panel3.grid(row=2,column=0)

    imgf4 = urllib.urlopen(url4)
    imgwr4 = StringIO.StringIO(imgf4.read())
    image4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgwr4))
    panel4 = tk.Label(root, image=image4)
    panel4.grid(row=3,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code demonstrates a lack of knowledge about basic programming tasks such as passing function arguments, using arrays, decomposing code into separate functions. Read http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+absolute+beginner+book

Comment: You say you add two buttons to your code but there are no buttons in your code. Are you asking how to create buttons, or how to get already-created buttons to call a function? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You just want buttons that run code when clicked?
What you do is draw a widget within your root `Frame`, such as a button or a menu field.
[Check out this example text editor](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/SimpleEditor.htm)

It's a text editor with a menu and a couple of buttons calling a method when you click 'it. No more. Easy to grok :)